# javascript regular expressions for password

Tags: javascript

i have to create a regular expression for password in java script with the following criteria
1. The password should contain atleast one alphabet either upper case or lower case
2. It should contain atleast one number
3. It should contain atlease one special character(`,~,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,_,+,=)

Comment: Not an answer, but my opinion is don't force this upon users. All it causes is users having to think of passwords they can't remember, and have to write down. [Here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cormac/papers/2009/SoLongAndNoThanks.pdf) is an interesting Microsoft research paper on the subject

Comment: The one thing I have not seen you test for is invalid characters like whitespace which you probably do not want. So if you are set on restricting the user then that is something you probably want to disallow as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var userpw = "musSTER123#";
var invalid = false;
if(!userpw.match(/\d/) || !userpw.match(/[a-zA-Z]/) || !userpw.match(/['~!@#$%&*_+=]/))
  invalid = true;

alert('pw is valid?' + !invalid);
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply its working good How can i make the user to enter atleast 6 characters and a maximum of 25 characters

Comment: "if(!(userpw.length >= 6 && userpw.length<=25)) invalid = true;" ? ^^

Comment: of with regex: "if(!userpw.match(/.{6,25}/)) invalid = true;"

Comment: Yes the second one is good to check thanks for the reply its working good Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Use these regexps:

- `[a-zA-Z]` for at least one letter
- `[0-9]` for at least one digit
- `['~!@#$%&*_+=^]` for at least one of the special characters you mentioned **OR**
- `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` for at least one character that is neither a letter nor a digit

But even better would be to support single-sign-on with OpenID, SSL client certificates or a way to make the browser store a long password in its password storage without even showing it to the user (maybe some password input that's prefilled by javascript and hidden with CSS).

Comment: Thanks for your reply i got it right using regular expression validator i added the following on custom expression "^.*(?=.{6,25})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[~`_!@#$%^&amp;*+=]).*$" But when i used the same in javascript its was not working. How can i restrict the user to enter only 6 to 25 characters in the above given expression

Answer (score 0):

Don't require strong passwords. They are fool's gold. Yes, a strong password is better than a weak one, all other things being equal. But all other things are rarely equal. A strong password is more likely than a weak one to end up on a post-it note stuck to the user's monitor.

A far better defence is a good lock-out policy. A system that does nothing more than disallow passwords containing dictionary words, but locks IP addresses out for one hour after three failed login attempts will still be over 99% secure after one year of constant battering by brute force. Also, you can make it much stronger by increasing the lock-out period for continued failed attempts.

Answer (score 0):

These posts were helpfull here is a bit of code some of you may want to use at some point. This forces the user to input an Uppercase, Lowercase, Special character, and minimum of 8 characters in length. It also breaks it up and lets them know what exactly it is they are doing wrong.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function validate() {

        if (document.aspnetForm.PasswordValue.value == '') {
            alert('Current Password is a required field!');
            document.aspnetForm.PasswordValue.focus()
            return false;
        }
        if (document.aspnetForm.NewPasswordValue.value == '') {
            alert('New Password is a required field!');
            document.aspnetForm.NewPasswordValue.focus()
            return false;
        }
        if (document.aspnetForm.NewPasswordValue.value.match(/\d/) == null) {
            alert('Your new password must have a number!');
            document.aspnetForm.NewPasswordValue.focus()
            return false;
        }
        if (document.aspnetForm.NewPasswordValue.value.match(/[a-z]/) == null) {
            alert('Your new password must have an Upper and lower case letter!');
            document.aspnetForm.NewPasswordValue.focus()
            return false;
        }
        if (document.aspnetForm.NewPasswordValue.value.match(/[A-Z]/) == null) {
            alert('Your new password must have an Upper and lower case letter!');
            document.aspnetForm.NewPasswordValue.focus()
            return false;
        }
        if (document.aspnetForm.NewPasswordValue.value.match(/['~!@#$%&*_+=]/) == null) {
            alert('Your new password must have a special character i.e.(!@#$%&*)');
            document.aspnetForm.NewPasswordValue.focus()
            return false;
        }
        if (document.aspnetForm.NewPasswordValue.value.length < 8) {
            alert('Your new password must have a minimum of 8 characters!');
            document.aspnetForm.NewPasswordValue.focus()
            return false;
        }
        if (document.aspnetForm.NewConfirmPassword.value == '') {
            alert('Confirm New Password is a required field!');
            document.aspnetForm.NewConfirmPassword.focus()
            return false;
        }
        if (document.aspnetForm.NewPasswordValue.value != document.aspnetForm.NewConfirmPassword.value) 
        {
            alert('New password and Confirm New Password do not match!');
            document.aspnetForm.NewConfirmPassword.focus()
            return false;
        }
        if (document.aspnetForm.PasswordValue.value == document.aspnetForm.NewPasswordValue.value) {
            alert('Your current password and new password are the same!');
            document.aspnetForm.NewPasswordValue.focus()
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```